# Active MQ - Listen For Messages

Tags: php, apache, activemq-classic

i have edited the portfolio example to read data from external source and publish it, it's working fine when i access it from http://localhost:8161/demo/portfolio/  the thing that have an app that i need it to listen to these messages and publish it i have copied the example to localhost/demo/portfolio/  but i can't seem to get it to work

can anyone help me and give me an example to do such thing, because i seems can't find anything like this